# How to Query Subdocuments of 1 Schema that match the contains of another Model Subdocument Schema

Tags: mean-stack

I am writing a MEAN stack application that defines the two (2) models.

```
var Job = db.model('Job', {
    ...
    kind: {
        baby: false,
        pet: false,
        house: false,
    }
});

var Person = db.model('Person', {
    ...
    kind: {
        baby: false,
        pet: false,
        house: false,
    }
});
```

I create the kind field as a sub-document since what is getting stored in this field is a input of type checkbox in my angularjs app.

My question relates to the query of Job for which the Person has the same kind equal to true.

For example, if a Person has checked baby and pet in their profile then I would like to query all Jobs that have baby and pet as true.

Is this the way to store checkbox inputs from a html form in mongodb? If so,
what is the query string to achieve my results. If not, what is the correct way
to store checkbox inputs in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the amount of data involved in the people and jobs collections neither the purpose of the query/main objective of the app. Based on that, here are some thoughts:

- Have an angular service to get the data from the people and jobs collections and store it as soon as the app loads. Everytime a checkbox is checked/unchecked use `ng-change` and custom angular filters on the service data to achieve what you want, instead of constantly querying the database;
- If you really want/need to query the database everytime the checkboxes are checked/unchecked then you can send a request to the server with the checkboxes values (something like this `{baby: false, pet: false, house: false}` in `req.body`). Once the request is received just query as usual and return the matching documents:

  ```
  var Job = mongoose.model('Job');
  Job.find({kind: req.body}, function (err, docs) {
      if(err) {
          // handle err
      }
      res.json(docs);
  });
  ```

Hope that helps but I can't be much more specific.

Comment: The purpose for the query is to display the current open Jobs that are within the interest of the Person so that the Person can apply for them.

My issue is the query itself. How do I query on a subdocument that contains a structure like 

kind: { baby: true,

Comment: pet: true, house: false }

Person
kind: { baby: true, pet: true, house: false }

I want to display all jobs that have the same Person.kind as the Job.kind